# Multiply Array position Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, logic, multiplication

I need to fix this code in Swift language. I don't know how can I to multiply array positions mut1 and mut2 values. The result is 8.

```
var mut1 = [7,-4,5]
var mut2 = [3,2,-1]

var multiply = mut1[0] * mut2[0] + mut1[1] * mut2[1] + mut1[2] * mut2[2]

print(multiply)
```

Comment: The code above results in 8. What exactly is your question? Please review [ask].

Comment: Yes the result is 8, what do you want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a Swift-like solution, you could try this:

```
var mut1 = [7,-4,5]
var mut2 = [3,2,-1]

var multiply = zip(mut1, mut2).map { $0 * $1 }.reduce(0, +)

print(multiply) // 8
```

Comment: Shorter: `zip(mut1, mut2).map(*).reduce(0, +)`

Answer (score 0):

Use "For" Loop to calculate the sum of same array position

```
var mut1 = [7,-4,5]
var mut2 = [3,2,-1]
var productsum = 0
 for i in 0..<mut1.count {
        let product = mut1[i] * mut2[i]
        productsum += product
    }
    print(productsum)
```